# URL Parameters to Populate Hosted PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf

Is it possible to populate the form fields with URL parameters of a PDF hosted on a 3rd party server?

For example, I'd like to collect user data via HTML input fields and use JavaScript to generate a link (which contains the URL parameters with variables defined in the input fields) to the government hosted 1040 form, where it would populate the form fields `first_name` and `last_name`.

Something like

`http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf?first_name=Mark&last_name=Miller`

Is this possible or would I need to host the PDF on a server where I could access the PDF's DOM?

Answer (score 0):

PDF doesn't have document object model or DOM. However, as far as I understand your question, you can generate pdf document from html page width dynamic content by using some server-side library. Check out this question if you are using PHP [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I am not looking to convert HTML to a PDF. I am trying to fill in the PDF form values via JavaScript.